# how to write a simple method in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, methods

I am a novice to java and have started to work with Eclipse.
I have created a group of arrays of strings and want to create a method that concatenates some members of each array and prints them out. But eclipse gives me back a syntax error.
This is my code

> ```
>    Public static void Printar() {
>           System.out.println("Array0[q] + Array1[r] + Array2[s] + >Array3[t] + Array4[u] + Array5[v] + Array6[w] ");
>
>           }
> ```

It concatenates each member of Array 1 to 6 (as a string) and then prints it out.
It says
1- Public cannot be resolved to a variable
2- Put semicolon to complete block statements(which I have
)
and some other error
Would somebody please help me to understand and figure out what the issue is.
Thanks a lot you all

Answer (score 2):

**Public cannot be resolved to a variable** means jvm can't understand what `Public` is:

`Public` should be small case. Java is case-sensitive and all keywords in java are small case.

```
Public static void Printar() {
```

should be

```
public static void Printar() {
```

**NOTE:** Java naming convention suggests that use first letter in method name as small case letter.

Answer (score 1):

`Public` should be `public` :

```
   public static void Printar() {
          System.out.println("Array0[q] + Array1[r] + Array2[s] + >Array3[t] + Array4[u] + Array5[v] + Array6[w] ");
   }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Have a very nice day!

Answer (score 1):

According to **`Java Naming Convention`**: -

All the java `identifiers` and `methods` should start with a lowercase letter or an underscore. Same is followed for every keyword defined for Java..

Since, `public` is a keyword, it starts with a lowercase letter.. So, it should be `public` rather than `Public`..

So you should basically change your method: -

```
Public static void Printar()
```

to: -

```
public static void printar()
```

**Notice** lowercase starting letter in `public` and your method `printar`.

Answer (score 0):

`Public` should be `public` (note the case)

I suspect your other errors will follow from this.

Answer (score 0):

`Public` needs to be `public`

```
public static void printar() {
    System.out.println("Array0[q] + Array1[r] + Array2[s] + >Array3[t] + Array4[u] + Array5[v] + Array6[w]");
    }
```

the Public needs to be lowercase. Also, the method name isn't affected by the case, but it is a general convention to have method names in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

I don't believe your `System.out.println()` will have the desired output. You mentioned you wanted to concatenate various arrays elements into a string, but your current code will just print that exact string you have inside.